# Graphite Web Error Log, OperationalError: no such table: auth_user

Tags: python-2.7, graphite

I have a problem with starting graphite web interface, using apache2. I get 500 Internal error, the screenshot of my log is below. I am new to this website and also to this software. My question might be too simple but, I have spent a lot of time on this. Thanks..

error log:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the database has not yet been created.  You can do so by running:

```
sudo -u _graphite graphite-manage syncdb --noinput
```

and that should clear up the 500 error.  This is a minimum to get started with Graphite, using the SQLite database.  It is possible to configure an alternate database in the local_settings.py file, in which case the above command is not necessary.  But with the default configuration, which uses SQLite as the back-end, this command should get you past the error.

Source: https://ianunruh.com/2014/05/monitor-everything-part-4.html